# Database updates not showing in Blazor app after inserted from form

Tags: .net, sqlite, razor, blazor

Fairly new to Blazor and even C# to some extent, I had this project working with just a locally stored list, but wanting to get it a little more full-featured so I wanted to add a DB so I have a sqlite database added here. The form updates the DB, but no matter what I do it won't show the changes until after I update the page.
The Form:

```
   <EditForm Model="_flipToCreate" OnInvalidSubmit="CreateFlip">
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label for="newItemName">Name</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="_flipToCreate.ItemName" class="form-control" id="flipName"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label for="newItemName">Buy</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="_flipToCreate.BuyPrice" class="form-control" id="flipBuy"></InputNumber>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label for="newItemName">Sell</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="_flipToCreate.SellPrice" class="form-control" id="flipSell"></InputNumber>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label for="newItemName">Quantity</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="_flipToCreate.Quantity" class="form-control" id="flipQuantity"></InputNumber>
    </div>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <button @onclick="CreateFlip" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    <button @onclick="CalculateFlip" class="btn btn-secondary">Calculate</button>

</EditForm>
```

The CreateFlip funciton:

```
    private async Task CreateFlip()
{
    await FlipDbContext.Flips.AddAsync(_flipToCreate);
    await FlipDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    StateHasChanged();
    _flipToCreate.ItemName = "Item name";
    _flipToCreate.BuyPrice = 0;
    _flipToCreate.SellPrice = 0;
    _flipToCreate.Quantity = 0;

}
```

I'm also wondering if anyone has any suggestions to posting other calculated valued to the db from the input of the form. I would need to add the margin based on the difference between buy and sell prices and the profit from that number times quantity.

Flip class:

```
    public class Flip
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int BuyPrice { get; set; }
    public int SellPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Margin { get; set; }
    public int Profit { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks to anyone in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't insert margin or profit.  Those can always be calculated values.  If you really want it in your class, make it read-only and override `get` to return the calculated value.

Comment: Please define " but no matter what I do it won't show the changes until after I update the page."  So what does it show?  The values you entered?  As it's coded the form should show the empty values.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis When the form gets submitted and the CreateFlip() fires, it adds everything to the DB without issue, but I can't see any of it until I refresh the page.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 How would I go about inserting them into the database or calculating them if they're outside of the <EditForm \>?

Comment: You don't insert variations of the same data.  If you know the buy price, sell price, and quantity, then you can easily use those to calculate margin and profit, so there's no benefit in saving that information to the DB.  In order to return those items in a database query, create a View in the database for that.